# Large JSON while exporting causing Memory Issues

Tags: python, json, mongodb, api, elasticsearch

**Problem:**

I have an API, which fetches data from elastic multiple indexes and combine it into one single JSON record and return when the API is called. Also the result fetched from the API is generally huge.

So iam having a wrapper script which gets all the data from API for a day. But here in my code iam having an array named `results`, when the data for the day is less Iam not getting an issue. But when the data fetched for the day is huge the entire array is sitting in the RAM and causing the system to slow down.

My primary intention of creating this array is to export in a mongo which in another network, which i can directly copy from my network.

**Code Snippet:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
import argparse
import sys
import logging
import MySQLdb
import requests
import json
import time



_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def get_samples(date,end):
    """
    Get Samples hashes form Database

    :param date: date of sample arrival
    :return list_of_hashes
    """
    try:
        results = []
        cur_time = time.time()
        with open('config.json','r') as c:
            config = json.load(c)
        _logger.info('Entering into database {}'.format(date))
        connection = MySQLdb.connect(config['malware_mysql'],"root","root","meta")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT MD5 from some where `Last_Seen` BETWEEN '{} 00:00:00' AND '{} 23:59:59'".format(date,end))
        hashes = cursor.fetchall()
        for hash in hashes:
            _logger.info('Hash {}'.format(hash[0]))
            try:
                response = requests.get('http://{}:{}/some/{}'.format(config['a'],config['b'],hash[0]))
                _logger.info('Result from API {}'.format(response))
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    results.append(json.loads(response.text))
                else:
                    _logger.error('Error in Querying API {} for hash {}'.format(response.status_code,hash))
            except Exception as e:
                _logger.error('Error in querying database {} - {}'.format(hash,e))
        connection.close()
        with open('{}_{}.json'.format(date,end),'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(results))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Bye')
    except Exception as e:
        _logger.error('Error in querying database final {}'.format(e))
    return '{} completed'.format(date)


def parse_args(args):
    """
    Parse command line parameters

    :param args: command line parameters as list of strings
    :return: command line parameters as :obj:`airgparse.Namespace`
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Enter date to Export")
    parser.add_argument(
        dest="date",
        help="Date of Sample Arrival in format 2018-08-16",
        )
    parser.add_argument(
        dest="end",
        help="Date of Sample Arrival end",
        )
    return parser.parse_args(args)


def main(args):
    args = parse_args(args)
    print("{} Samples are quiered -- {}".format(args.date, get_samples(args.date,args.end)))
    _logger.info("Script ends here")


def run():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)
    main(sys.argv[1:])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

**Why iam doing this?**
I want to export entire day's records from the API and transfer this JSON file to mongo using mongoimport.

**What i needed?**
Alternative solution to prevent this entire array sit in the RAM and cause system slow down. Other solution which makes the solution more efficient.

Comment: What part is causing the memory issue? Loading from the DB? Saving to a JSON file? Parsing with json.loads?

Answer (score 1):

From what I gathered, you cannot connect directly to your Mongo DB, is that right? Could you spin up a MongoDB locally? This way you could use a Mongo Python library for saving results as you get them, use [`mongoexport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) to extract them as a JSON file, and then import them in your final DB?

Now to go back to your question, here are a couple of suggestions:

- Close your connection to MySQL `connection.close()` as soon as you get the info you need, so right after `hashes = cursor.fetchall()`
- `json.loads(response.text)` is also known under a nicer API `response.json()`
- Instead of appending to a `results` list in memory, you could write directly to the file

Putting it all together, without Keyboard interrupt handling, only changing the `get_samples` function:

```
def get_samples(date, end):
    with open('{}_{}.json'.format(date, end), 'w') as out_file:
        out_file.write('[\n')
        with open('config.json','r') as c:
            config = json.load(c)
        _logger.info('Entering into database {}'.format(date))
        connection = MySQLdb.connect(config['malware_mysql'],"root","root","meta")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT MD5 from some where `Last_Seen` BETWEEN '{} 00:00:00' AND '{} 23:59:59'".format(date, end)
        )
        hashes = cursor.fetchall()
        connection.close()
        for hash in hashes:
            _logger.info('Hash {}'.format(hash[0]))
            try:
                response = requests.get('http://{}:{}/some/{}'.format(config['a'],config['b'],hash[0]))
                _logger.info('Result from API {}'.format(response))
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    out_file.write(response.json() + ',\n')
                else:
                    _logger.error('Error in Querying API {} for hash {}'.format(response.status_code,hash))
            except Exception as e:
                _logger.error('Error in querying database {} - {}'.format(hash,e))
        out_file.write(']\n')
```

I haven't tried this code, so there might be a syntax error somewhere. Hopefully, that should get you close enough.

If the memory usage is still high, note that the Requests library has [a streaming mode](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests), which could potentially help further.